# What is the symbolic variable for "public address"?

Tags: apache-httpd, ip-address

Please forgive my ignorance for asking this question. I'm having a heck of a time discovering how to specify "public address" instead of hard coding and IP address.

According to the Apache manual [Binding to Addresses and Ports](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/bind.html):

> ***How This Works With Virtual Hosts***
>   The Listen directive does not implement Virtual Hosts - it only tells
>   the main server what addresses and ports to listen on. If no
>    directives are used, the server will behave in the same
>   way for all accepted requests. However,  can be used to
>   specify a different behavior for one or more of the addresses or
>   ports. To implement a VirtualHost, the server must first be told to
>   listen to the address and port to be used. Then a 
>   section should be created for the specified address and port to set
>   the behavior of this virtual host. Note that if the  is
>   set for an address and port that the server is not listening to, it
>   cannot be accessed.

And the manual gives examples like:

> ```
> Listen 0.0.0.0:80
> Listen 192.0.2.1:80
> ```

Hard-coding an IP address is problematic for us because the hosting provider changes the IP address on occasion. We want something that "just works" all the time without intervention. The last time it changed I was out of town on business so the site was down for just over a week.

We tried some guesses like the following, but it resulted in the server not starting:

```
Listen ${PUBLIC_IP}:80
```

What is the variable name that specifies "public address"?

Comment: On socket listening, `0.0.0.0` means listen all IP.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi all IPv4 only (which may be desirable in some cases of course).

Comment: Then you can add `::` (i.e. `Listen [::]:80`) for IPv6 as well.

Comment: @grawity but then you might as well just say `Listen 80`...

Answer (score 8):

I don't think there is such a variable, but you don't need one — just tell Apache to listen on port 80 on all interfaces:

```
Listen 80
```

Unless you have multiple IP addresses and you want Apache to only listen on a subset, that will work fine and adapt to changing IP addresses.